# Add Rows to Table With Macro

Tags: tables, rules

I've read the answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341916/command-to-continually-add-to-table-with-a-command-macro) but haven't been able to modify the code to allow me to insert `\hline` between each row added to my table.

How can the code by modified to insert `\hline` each time a new row is defined?

So there would be a line between R1C1 | R1C2 and R2C1 | R2C2 just like there's a line between the headers and the main table contents.

[image: Table without bordered rows]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insertion of `\@gobble` at the start of `\foorows` in the [linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341925/5764) is meant to gobble the first `&` of the row. You can insert `\hline` just before that to always insert a horizontal rule with every `\addtotable`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\foorows{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addtotable[1]{%
  \g@addto@macro\foorows{\hline\@gobble}% Insert horizontal rule and gobble first &
  \@for\tmp:=#1\do{%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\foorows
      \expandafter{\expandafter&\tmp}%
  }%
  \g@addto@macro\foorows{\\}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\addtotable{R1C1,R1C2,R1C3,R1C4}
\addtotable{R2C1,R2C2,R2C3,R2C4}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| }
    \hline
    Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 & Header 4 \\ \hline % Header row
    \foorows
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for you prompt and informative reply.