# Reset a sub-macro at every run of the macro

Tags: macros

I'm trying to build a macro to generate a whole changelog table *dynamically* (template for professional document - prototype). I've found several useful answers to achieve it, but I'm stuck on a macro reset inside another.

*Warning : I've detailled everything so that the path I took is clear, instead of posting the code not working and expect an answer...*

### My goal :

Have a macro to build dynamically a changelog table in the document :

- Declare the version in the preamble :

  ```
  \newrow{A}{H. Potter,R. Weasley}{First release for Snape}
  \newrow{B}{H. Granger}{Fixed tons of typos}
  ```

  => Comma-separated list of authors and/or modifications on sepearate table lines.
- Build the table in the core (with the macro `\modifications` being the point of this question) :

  ```
  \setlength\extrarowheight{4.5pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{LOG OF CHANGES}}\\[2.25pt]
      \hline
      Version & \centering{Author} & {Modification} \\[2.25pt] \hline
     \modifications     % <-- TABLE BUILD HERE DEPENDING ON HOW MANY ROWS THEY ARE...
  \end{tabularx}
  ```

This should done this : 
[image: Goal to achieve]

Currently, this table is achieved with this code. Nothing fancy except the `\specialcell` that allows line breaks.

```
% Command to brake line in a cell.
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}
}

% Construction of the tabular
\setlength\extrarowheight{4.5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{LOG OF CHANGES}}\\[2.25pt]
    \hline
    Version & \centering{Author} & {Modification} \\[2.25pt] \hline
    A & \specialcell{H. Potter\\R. Weasley} & \specialcell[l]{First release for Snape\\Additions to Fred's old version} \\ \hline
    B & \specialcell{H. Granger} & Fixed tons of typos ! \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

---

**Problem 0 :** Break the line when a comma-separated list of authors and/or modification is entered. This has been solved with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell).

**Problem 1 :** I don't know beforehand how much version are they going to be created !

I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357577/add-rows-to-table-with-macro) to build a table "dynamically", in function of the number of commands `\addtotable{}` passed. Seems the right way! I tried thus to combine that with my case, and it worked.

Here's the code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=4.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter

% Command to brake line in a cell.
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}
}

\newcommand\modifications{} % macro containing whole code to build all the lines of the table
\newcommand\authorsList{}   % macro containing the code for the authors list
\newcommand\modifList{}     % macro containing the code for the modifications list

\newcommand{\newrow}[3]{
    % Version cell of the table
    \g@addto@macro\modifications{#1 &}
    % build \specialcell{Element1\\Element2} and put it the second cell
    \g@addto@macro\authorsList{\@gobble}
    \@for\tmp:=#2\do{%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\authorsList
        \expandafter{\expandafter\\\tmp}
    }%
    \g@addto@macro\modifications{\specialcell{\authorsList}&}
    % build \specialcell{Element1\\Element2} and put it the third cell
    \g@addto@macro\modifList{\@gobble}
    \@for\tmp:=#3\do{%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\modifList
        \expandafter{\expandafter\\\tmp}
    }%
    \g@addto@macro\modifications{\specialcell[l]{\modifList}}
    % end table
    \g@addto@macro\modifications{\\\hline}
}
\makeatother

% Version definitions
\newrow{A}{H. Potter,R. Weasley}{First release for Snape, Additions to Fred's old version}
%\newrow{B}{H. Granger}{Fixed tons of typos}

\begin{document}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{4.5pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{LOG OF CHANGES}}\\[2.25pt]
        \hline
        Version & \centering{Author} & {Modification} \\[2.25pt] \hline
       \modifications     % <-- build of the table
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

It work pretty well with 1 line in the table.Then I ran into another problem when I added

### Main problem

The macros `modifList` and `authorsList` are not reset and then it meesses everything up. I tired forceing them to reset in the begin with `\let\authorsList\@empty` and with `\let\modifList\@empty`, but then it only keeps the last value.

At some point, the values that goes into the `\specialcell` are not the current ones, but all from the beginning...

Here's the current output :

[image: Wrong output]

and the code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=4.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter

% Command to brake line in a cell.
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}
}

\newcommand\modifications{} % macro containing whole code to build all the lines of the table
\newcommand\authorsList{}   % macro containing the code for the authors list
\newcommand\modifList{}     % macro containing the code for the modifications list

\newcommand{\newrow}[3]{
    % Version cell of the table
    \g@addto@macro\modifications{#1 &}
    % build \specialcell{Element1\\Element2} and put it the second cell
    \g@addto@macro\authorsList{\@gobble}
    \@for\tmp:=#2\do{%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\authorsList
        \expandafter{\expandafter\\\tmp}
    }%
    \g@addto@macro\modifications{\specialcell{\authorsList}&}
    % build \specialcell{Element1\\Element2} and put it the third cell
    \g@addto@macro\modifList{\@gobble}
    \@for\tmp:=#3\do{%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\modifList
        \expandafter{\expandafter\\\tmp}
    }%
    \g@addto@macro\modifications{\specialcell[l]{\modifList}}
    % end table
    \g@addto@macro\modifications{\\\hline}
}
\makeatother

% Version definitions
\newrow{A}{H. Potter,R. Weasley}{First release for Snape, Additions to Fred's old version}
\newrow{B}{H. Granger}{Fixed tons of typos}

\begin{document}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{4.5pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{LOG OF CHANGES}}\\[2.25pt]
        \hline
        Version & \centering{Author} & {Modification} \\[2.25pt] \hline
       \modifications     % <-- build of the table
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas on how to make this work with multiple versions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `\authorsList` and `\modifList` must be expanded, when you add them to `\modifications`. Otherwise their last meaning will be used. Adding a lot of `\expandafter`s does it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=4.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter

% Command to brake line in a cell.
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}
}

\newcommand\modifications{} % macro containing whole code to build all the lines of the table
\newcommand\authorsList{}   % macro containing the code for the authors list
\newcommand\modifList{}     % macro containing the code for the modifications list

\newcommand{\newrow}[3]{
    % Version cell of the table
    \g@addto@macro\modifications{#1 &}
    % build \specialcell{Element1\\Element2} and put it the second cell
    \gdef\authorsList{\@gobble}
    \@for\tmp:=#2\do{%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\authorsList
        \expandafter{\expandafter\\\tmp}
    }%
    % added \expandafter's here
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\modifications
        \expandafter{\expandafter\specialcell\expandafter{\authorsList}&}
    % build \specialcell{Element1\\Element2} and put it the third cell
    \gdef\modifList{\@gobble}
    \@for\tmp:=#3\do{%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\modifList
        \expandafter{\expandafter\\\tmp}
    }%
    % added \expandafter's here
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\modifications
        \expandafter{\expandafter\specialcell
        \expandafter[\expandafter l\expandafter]\expandafter{\modifList}}
    % end table
    \g@addto@macro\modifications{\\\hline}
}
\makeatother

% Version definitions
\newrow{A}{H. Potter,R. Weasley}{First release for Snape, Additions to Fred's old version}
\newrow{B}{H. Granger}{Fixed tons of typos}

\begin{document}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{4.5pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{LOG OF CHANGES}}\\[2.25pt]
        \hline
        Version & \centering{Author} & {Modification} \\[2.25pt] \hline
       \modifications     % <-- build of the table
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a problem of expansion: you have to add the expansion of `\AuthorsList` and `\modifList`.

You should also be careful with spaces in your code: a new line in the body of a definition counts for a space in the output unless it is masked by `%`.

I propose an `expl3` based code that, besides easing the expansion problems, avoids worrying about unprotected end-of-lines.

You may appreciate the easier code for transforming the comma separated list into a `\\` separated list for `\specialcell`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=4.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\printchanges}{}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \par\noindent
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.5pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{LOG~OF~CHANGES}}\\[2.5pt]
  \hline
  Version & Author & Modification \\[2.5pt]
  \hline
  \tl_use:N \g_eisenheim_modifications_tl
  \end{tabularx}
  \group_end:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\newrow}{mmm}
 {
  \eisenheim_newrow:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\specialcell}{O{c}m}
 {
  \eisenheim_specialcell:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \g_eisenheim_modifications_tl
\seq_new:N \l__eisenheim_specialcell_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \eisenheim_newrow:nnn
 {
  % add the tag
  \tl_put_right:Nn \g_eisenheim_modifications_tl { #1 & }
  % add the authors
  % first split the text at commas
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__eisenheim_specialcell_seq { #2 }
  % then add the items separated by \\
  \tl_put_right:Nx \g_eisenheim_modifications_tl
   {
     \specialcell { \seq_use:Nn \l__eisenheim_specialcell_seq { \\ } } &
   }
  % add the description
  \tl_put_right:Nn \g_eisenheim_modifications_tl { #3 \\[2.5pt] \hline }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \eisenheim_specialcell:nn
 {
  \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Version definitions
\newrow{A}{H. Potter,R. Weasley}{First release for Snape, Additions to Fred's old version}
\newrow{B}{H. Granger}{Fixed tons of typos}

\begin{document}

\printchanges

\end{document}
```

[image]