# Add Rows to Table With Macro (calc fields result the same for each row)

Tags: tables, macros, calculations, xparse, optional-arguments

I use as template macro from this articale: [Add Rows to Table With Macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357577/add-rows-to-table-with-macro).
All work fine if values in cells not to calculate. But othewise results of calculation is the same for each row. How to avoid this problem?
Log-file ref: https://yadi.sk/i/vgnoGKni3SLZGD.

```
   \documentclass[oneside,final,14pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage {listing}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage {etoolbox}
\usepackage {expl3}
\usepackage[parse-numbers=true,round-precision=4,round-mode=figures,exponent-product=\cdot]{siunitx}
\usepackage{siunitx} % Provides the \SI{}{} command for typesetting SI units, набор значений единиц измерения
\usepackage {calculator}
\usepackage {fp}
\usepackage {tikz}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}% дополнение, чтобы были пробелы в именах
\grffilesetup{% дополнение, чтобы имена файлов могли быть кириллицей (под Windows)
  encoding,
  filenameencoding=cp1251
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\huge}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}

 \usepackage{verbatim}
 %Поддержка отступов
\usepackage{vmargin}
% Работа с надписями
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
%Для окрашивания текста и не только
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usepackage {ifpdf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%Ссылки и закладки содержание всатвка текста
\usepackage{filecontents}
 %control over PDF bookmarks
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{soul}
%Математический пакет
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\usepackage {rotating}
\usepackage{amscd}
%Для обращения к цвету по имени
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm} % математические дополнения от АМС
\usepackage{indentfirst} % отделять первую строку раздела абзацным отступом тоже

\usepackage{multirow} % улучшенное форматирование таблиц
\usepackage{ulem} % подчеркивания
% стиль для для страницы (колонтитулы)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%Для списка литературы по ГОСТ
\usepackage[strict]{csquotes}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{gost2008}
\bibliographystyle{utf8gost705u}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-15pt}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[space]{grffile} \grffilesetup{encoding,filenameencoding=cp1251}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ifmtarg


\begin{document} 

\definecolor{danger}{HTML}{FE996B}
\definecolor{safety}{HTML}{9AFF99}
\definecolor{warning}{HTML}{FFA500}
\newcommand\dangColor[3]{
\FPeval{\tmp}{#1}
\FPeval{\tevdd}{#2+#3}
\FPifgt{\tmp}{#3}{\gdef\era{\cellcolor{warning}}}\else{\gdef\era{\cellcolor{danger}}}\fi
\FPifgt{\tmp}{\tevdd}{\gdef\era{\cellcolor{safety}}}\else{}\fi
\era}
\newcommand\foorows{}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\addtotable}{m O{---} O{---}O{---}}{%
  \g@addto@macro\foorows{\hline\@gobble}% Insert horizontal rule and gobble first &
  \@for\tmp:=#1\do{%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\foorows
      \expandafter{\expandafter&\tmp}%  
            }%
\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\foorows
      \expandafter{\expandafter&#3}
\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\foorows
      \expandafter{\expandafter&#4}
\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\foorows
      \expandafter{\expandafter&#2}
\FPeval{\neobhTd}{#2 *0.8}

\IfInteger{#2}{\def\neobhT{\num[round-mode = places, round-precision = 0, round-half = up]{\neobhTd}}}{\def\neobhT{---}}
\newboolean{b3}
\newboolean{b4}
\IfInteger{#3}{\setboolean{b3}{true}}{\setboolean{b3}{false}}
\IfInteger{#4}{\setboolean{b4}{true}}{\setboolean{b4}{false}}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{b3} \AND \boolean{b4}}
{\FPeval{\tevd}{#3+#4}
\def\tev{\num[zero-decimal-to-integer]{\tevd}}
\def\ku{\dangColor{\neobhTd}{#3}{#4}}
}
{
\def\tev{---}
\def\ku{}
}
\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\foorows
      \expandafter{\expandafter&\ku\neobhT}
            %%
\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\foorows
      {\expandafter&\ku\tev}
  \g@addto@macro\foorows{\\}%
}
\newcommand\tabKT{
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
%\mycccc
\rowcolor[HTML]{96FFFB} 
Name 1 &\ Name 2 &\makecell{t1\textsubscript{n}, s} &\makecell{t2\textsubscript{r}, s}&\makecell{t3\textsubscript{b}, s}& \makecell{0,8·t\textsubscript{b}, s}&\makecell{t\textsubscript{e}, s}\\ \hline

\foorows
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\end{table}
}
\addtotable{name,name}[140][30][120]
\addtotable{name,name}[600][48][400]
\addtotable{name,name}[800][120][200]
\tabKT

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please make the document complete (with `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, packages, etc. to make it easier to reproduce the output? Also, could you explain which calculations should be performed on the three cells in each column? And welcome to TeX.SE of course!

Comment: It's pretty awful code. If you tell me how to calculate the entries in columns 7 and 8 I can show you a better way to do this.

Comment: Here content of log file reference: https://yadi.sk/i/vgnoGKni3SLZGD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\sisetup{
  parse-numbers=true,
  round-precision=4,
  round-mode=figures,
  exponent-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
  output-decimal-marker={,}
}


\definecolor{danger}{HTML}{FE996B}
\definecolor{safety}{HTML}{9AFF99}
\definecolor{warning}{HTML}{FFA500}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtotable}{mmmmm}
 {
  #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5
  & \cellcolor{ \yaroslav_color:nnn { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } } \fp_to_decimal:n { #5 * 0.8 }
  & \cellcolor{ \yaroslav_color:nnn { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } } \fp_to_decimal:n { #3 + #4 }
  \\
  \hline
 }
\cs_new:Nn \yaroslav_color:nnn
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 + #2 > #3*0.8 } { green } { red }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{96FFFB}%
Name 1 &\ Name 2 & {$t1_n,s$} & {$t2_r,s$} & {$t3_b,s$} & {$0{,}8\cdot t_b,s$} & {$t_e,s$} \\
\hline
\addtotable{name}{name}{140}{30}{120}
\addtotable{name}{name}{600}{48}{400}
\addtotable{name}{name}{800}{120}{200}
\addtotable{name}{name}{1}{1}{12}
\end{tabular}

\caption{My caption}\label{my-label}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to do microbrunch? For diffrent conditions - diffrent clolors?

Comment: @YaroslavAntropov You can nest conditionals.