# How can I add a \hline on a macro created table

Tags: tables, macros, arrays, auxiliary-files, hline

I'm trying to create a table dynamically by adding rows to it.

The idea is that the table has to be used/created before the rows are appended using a macro. I modified the method described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357577/add-rows-to-table-with-macro) In order to use an auxiliary file so I can use the append macro after the table is created.

The code I have so far is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\def\tmprevisionrows{}
\def\revisionrows{}

\makeatletter
\def\appendrevision#1{\g@addto@macro\tmprevisionrows{ #1}}

\newcommand\addrevision[4]{%
    \appendrevision{#1 & #2 & #3 & #4 \\[10pt]}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\revisions}{
\begin{center}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X | X |}
 \hline
    VERSION & MODIFICATION & DATE & AUTHOR \\[10pt]
 \hline
 \revisionrows
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\@starttoc{xyz}
\makeatother

\revisions

% Notice that we are appending after using the \revisions macro
\addrevision{0.1}{Document Creation}{01/01/2020}{Author Name}
\addrevision{0.2}{Document Modified}{02/01/2020}{Author Name}

\addtocontents{xyz}{\gdef\protect\revisionrows{\tmprevisionrows}}

\end{document}
```

The result is the following (As you can see no `\hline` on the table is added):

[image]

When I try to add an `\hline` anywhere I get a compilation error. How I can add an `\hline` (or alternative) to every row appended using my macro?

Answer (score 1):

Change your macro `\addrevision` into

```
\newcommand\addrevision[4]{%
    \appendrevision{#1 & #2 & #3 & #4 \\[10pt] \protect\hline}
}
```

and remove the trailing `\hline` in the definition of `\revisions`

```
\newcommand{\revisions}{
  \begin{center}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l | X | l | l |}
  \hline
  VERSION & MODIFICATION & DATE & AUTHOR \\[10pt]
  \hline
  \revisionrows
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{center}
}
```

I'd use a single `X` column, for the one with possible long data.

[image]

You can use the `.aux` file, instead of `.xyz`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\revisionrows{}
\newcounter{revisions}
\newcommand\addrevision[4]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \unexpanded{\add@revision{#1 & #2 & #3 & #4 \\[10pt] \hline}}%
  }%
  \stepcounter{revisions}%
}
\newcommand{\add@revision}[1]{%
  \g@addto@macro\revisionrows{#1}%
}
\AtEndDocument{\refstepcounter{revisions}\label{count@revisions}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\revisions}{%
  \begin{center}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l | X | l | l |}
  \hline
  VERSION & MODIFICATION & DATE & AUTHOR \\[10pt]
  \hline
  \revisionrows
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\revisions

% Notice that we are appending after using the \revisions macro
\addrevision{0.1}{Document Creation}{01/01/2020}{Author Name}
\addrevision{0.2}{Document Modified}{02/01/2020}{Author Name}

\end{document}
```

With this code, you'll receive a `Label(s) may have changed` warning if the number of revisions is different from the one found from the previous run.

Comment: Amazing! It works perfectly