# How to add rows to a table via a command

Tags: macros, expansion, xparse, tabularray

I'd like to do something very similar to this question here:
[Add Rows to Table With Macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357577/add-rows-to-table-with-macro)

However, I cannot get it to work with my case of a version log table created with the `tabularray` package and `xparse` commands.

My current MNWE (minimum not working example ...) is this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\makeatletter

\let\@history\@empty
\NewDocumentCommand \historyentry {m m m} {%
  \g@addto@macro\@history{#1 & #2 & #2\\}
}

\NewDocumentCommand \history {} {%
  \begin{tblr}{colspec={l l l}}
    Version & Date & Comment \\ 
    \@history{}
  \end{tblr}
}
\makeatother

\historyentry{1.0}{2023-03-01}{First release}
\historyentry{2.0}{2023-03-15}{Second release}

\begin{document}
\history
\end{document}
```

which when compiled using LuaLaTeX (or PDFLaTeX for that matter) results in this error:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2023-01-24> (/home/mnoethe/.local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/mnoethe/.local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/home/mnoethe/.local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty (/home/mnoethe/.local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/home/mnoethe/.local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def))) (/home/mnoethe/.local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabularray/tabularray.sty) (./test.aux) (/home/mnoethe/.local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\@history ->1.0 &
                  2023-03-01 & 2023-03-01\\2.0 & 2023-03-15 & 2023-03-15\\
l.25 \history
           
?
```

Any help on this would be appreciated!

The same code works when using a standard `\begin{tabular}{l l l}` instead of the `\begin{tblr}{colspec={l l l}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `tabularray` to first expand the `\@history` macro before typesetting the tabular. You can do this using the `expand` option (see section 3.2.3 "Expand Macros First" of the `tabularray` package manual):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\makeatletter
\let\@history\@empty
\NewDocumentCommand \historyentry {m m m} {%
  \g@addto@macro\@history{#1 & #2 & #3 \\}
}

\NewDocumentCommand \history {} {%
  \begin{tblr}[expand=\@history]{colspec={l l l}}
    Version & Date & Comment \\ 
    \@history{}
  \end{tblr}
}
\makeatother

\historyentry{1.0}{2023-03-01}{First release}
\historyentry{2.0}{2023-03-15}{Second release}

\begin{document}
\history
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works great!