Creating good tabularx
try to create "Datenblatt der Schule zur Weitergabe an die Polizei", maybe someone else knows it. In this document I created the table below.
The table looks good for me, but i know i make many mistakes.
To perform better, what is wrong or what should I change?
Especially the \necommand{amt}looks a bit strange for me, but it works.
Thanks
Patrick
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\newcommand{\Ab}{ \\[.5cm]}
\newcommand{\Zl}{\strut \\ \hline}


\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}%für Farben
\usepackage{tabularx, longtable} %für tabularx
\usepackage{colortbl}%um die Linien der Tabellen zu färben
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Farbe und Dicke der Linien festlegen
\arrayrulecolor{gray!80} % Farbe der Linien
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5mm} % Dicke der Linien

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\amt}[1]{\vspace{.1mm}\centering\textbf{#1}}



% Title Page
\title{M. Datenblatt der Schule zur Weitergabe an die Polizei}
\author{Dr. Norman Patrick Benner, Sicherheitsbeauftragter}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
    
    
    {\small % Schriftgröße verkleinern
        %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % Horizontale Abstände verkleinern
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8} % Vertikale Abstände verkleinern
        
        
        
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L|L|>{\footnotesize}L}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{l}{} \\[-1ex]
            \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{\large Mitglieder schulisches Krisenteam}} \\[2ex]
            \hline
            &&\\[-1ex]
            Name & Anschrift & \normalsize Telefon \\[2ex]
            \hline
            
            \amt{Schulleitung} & & Büro:\newline 456900 \\
            asDF, Markus & asdf & Privat:\newline 4757486576 \\
            & asdf & Mobil:\newline 4756475 \\
            \hline
            
            \amt{Stellvertretende Schulleitung} & & Büro:\newline 450  \\
            ASDF, Uwe & asdf & Privat:\newline 4757486576 \\
            & asdf & Mobil:\newline 4756475 \\
            \hline
            
            \amt{Studienleiterin} & & Büro:\newline 456 \\
            ASDF, Melanie & asdf & Privat:\newline 4757486576 \\
            & asdf & Mobil:\newline 4756475 \\
            \hline
            
            \amt{Fachbereichsleiter} & & Büro:\newline 44100 \\
            NGGFG, Claudia & asdf & Privat:\newline 4757486576 \\
            & asdf & Mobil:\newline 4756475 \\
            \hline
            
            \amt{Fachbereichsleiter} & & Büro:\newline 4564068 \\
            GGG, Jens & asdf & Privat:\newline 4757486576 \\
            & asdf & Mobil:\newline 4756475 \\
            \hline
            
            \amt{Fachbereichsleiter} & & Büro:\newline 45+485\\
            GGG, Marco & asdf & Privat:\newline 4757486576 \\
            & asdf & Mobil:\newline 4756475 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    } % Ende der Gruppe
    
    
\end{document}


IMHO the \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8} is too much and results in Büro is touching the line above.

I'd remove the vertical rules that do nothing useful. And also all manually inserted vertical spaces. The booktabs horizontal rules take care of that.
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\arrayrulecolor{gray!80} % Farbe der Linien
%\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5mm} % Dicke der Linien

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\amt}[1]{{\centering\textbf{#1}\\}}



% Title Page
\title{M. Datenblatt der Schule zur Weitergabe an die Polizei}
\author{Dr. Norman Patrick Benner, Sicherheitsbeauftragter}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}


{\small % Schriftgröße verkleinern
\noindent % <--- don't forget!
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LL>{\footnotesize}L@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{\large Mitglieder schulisches Krisenteam}} \\
\midrule
Name & Anschrift & \normalsize Telefon \\
\midrule

\amt{Schulleitung} & & Büro:\newline 456900 \\
asDF, Markus & asdf & Privat:\newline 4757486576 \\
& asdf & Mobil:\newline 4756475 \\
\midrule

\amt{Stellvertretende Schulleitung} & & Büro:\newline 450  \\
ASDF, Uwe & asdf & Privat:\newline 4757486576 \\
& asdf & Mobil:\newline 4756475 \\
\midrule

\amt{Studienleiterin} & & Büro:\newline 456 \\
ASDF, Melanie & asdf & Privat:\newline 4757486576 \\
& asdf & Mobil:\newline 4756475 \\
\midrule

\amt{Fachbereichsleiter} & & Büro:\newline 44100 \\
NGGFG, Claudia & asdf & Privat:\newline 4757486576 \\
& asdf & Mobil:\newline 4756475 \\
\midrule

\amt{Fachbereichsleiter} & & Büro:\newline 4564068 \\
GGG, Jens & asdf & Privat:\newline 4757486576 \\
& asdf & Mobil:\newline 4756475 \\
\midrule

\amt{Fachbereichsleiter} & & Büro:\newline 45+485\\
GGG, Marco & asdf & Privat:\newline 4757486576 \\
& asdf & Mobil:\newline 4756475 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

} % Ende der Gruppe (with a blank line before!)

\end{document}



Thanks, this is near to the table how it originally looks like, will see which one i take.

Speaking for myself (who else?), I'd go for a more compact-looking design in the right-hand columns. I'd also do fewer font size changes.

\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{array}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
%\newcommand{\Ab}{ \\[.5cm]}
%\newcommand{\Zl}{\strut \\ \hline}


%\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}%für Farben
\usepackage{tabularx} %für tabularx
\usepackage{colortbl}%um die Linien der Tabellen zu färben
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

% Farbe und Dicke der Linien festlegen
\arrayrulecolor{gray!80} % Farbe der Linien
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5mm} % Dicke der Linien

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\amt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

% Title Page
\title{M.\ Datenblatt der Schule zur Weitergabe an die Polizei}
\author{Dr.\ Norman Patrick Benner,\\ Sicherheitsbeauftragter}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\begingroup   
%\small % Schriftgröße verkleinern
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % Horizontale Abstände verkleinern
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8} % Vertikale Abstände verkleinern

\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % <-- new


\noindent % <-- new
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L|L|lL @{}}
   \hline

   \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\textbf{\large Mitglieder schulisches Krisenteam}} \\[0.5ex]
   \hline
   \amt{Name} & \amt{Anschrift} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Telefonnummern} \\[0.5ex]
   \hline

   \amt{Schulleitung} & & Büro &  456900 \\
   asDF, Markus & asdf & Privat &  4757486576 \\
   & asdf & Mobil &  4756475 \\
   \hline

   \amt{Stellv. Schulleitung} & & Büro &  450  \\
   ASDF, Uwe & asdf & Privat &  4757486576 \\
   & asdf & Mobil &  4756475 \\
   \hline

   \amt{Studienleiterin} & & Büro &  456 \\
   ASDF, Melanie & asdf & Privat &  4757486576 \\
   & asdf & Mobil &  4756475 \\
   \hline

   \amt{Fachbereichsleiter} & & Büro &  44100 \\
   NGGFG, Claudia & asdf & Privat &  4757486576 \\
   & asdf & Mobil &  4756475 \\
   \hline

   \amt{Fachbereichsleiter} & & Büro &  4564068 \\
   GGG, Jens & asdf & Privat &  4757486576 \\
   & asdf & Mobil &  4756475 \\
   \hline

   \amt{Fachbereichsleiter} & & Büro &  45+485\\
   GGG, Marco & asdf & Privat &  4757486576 \\
   & asdf & Mobil &  4756475 \\
   \hline

\end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\end{document}


Thanks, looks good. I like it.

If you are up to trying tabularray and macros my suggestion would be something like the following to separate content and layout a bit more:
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\makeatletter
\let\@list\@empty
\NewDocumentCommand \listentry {mmmmmmm} {%
    \g@addto@macro\@list{{\textbf{#1} \\ #2} & {#3 \\ #4} & {Büro:\\ \hspace*{1cm}+49/#5 \\ Privat:\\ \hspace*{1cm}+49/#6 \\ Mobil:\\ \hspace*{1cm}+49/#7}\\}
}

\begin{document}        
        \listentry{Schulleiter}{Müller, Peter}{Musterstraße 3}{00000 Musterstadt}{123/4567889}{123/4567889}{123/4567889}
        \listentry{Stellvertretende\\ Schulleitung}{Meier, Uwe}{Musterstraße 4}{00000 Musterstadt}{123/4567889}{123/4567889}{123/4567889}
        \listentry{Studienleiterin}{Schultze, Melanie}{Musterstraße 7}{00000 Musterstadt}{123/4567889}{123/4567889}{123/4567889}
        
        \begin{tblr}[expand=\@list]{
                rows={font=\small},
                colspec={XXX},
                hlines = {gray},
                vline{2,3}={solid,gray}, % I do recommend not using vertical lines in tables though
                column{Z}={font=\scriptsize},
                column{1}={halign=c},
                row{1}= {font=\bfseries\normalsize},
                row{2}={font=\bfseries,halign=c},
                }
            \SetCell[c=3]{c}{Mitglieder schulisches Krisenteam}\\
            Name & Anschrift & Telefon\\
            \@list
        \end{tblr}  
\end{document} 

The credit for the way the macro works goes to this answer by Jasper Habicht: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/679619/118712
If you prefer sticking to tabularx I suggest the booktabs-package with the \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule commands to improve on the spacing.

Thanks, i will try this maybe with the look from Mico, but is not what i looks like in original.

In that case, you could have specified you were actually trying to recreate the original layout in your question. Maybe you can update your question with a screenshot of the actual document, then people can help you more effectively.

I tried to recreate the original, but now i think there is no reason that i may not create a better looking table.
Patrick
