# Add rows to a table with a macro after the table is shown

Tags: tables, macros, longtable, expansion, rules

I'm trying to have a command to be executed at the begining of the document in order to append a value to a variable after it is being used. The idea is to combine it with [Add Rows to Table With Macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357577/add-rows-to-table-with-macro) in order to have the table row to be inserted after the table is used.

Since the `\addtotable` is called after the usage of `\foorows` the row is never appended to the table. Futhermore, the table should allow **page breaking** if not fitting in a page (I guess that using *longtable* will be enough).

I would like the following example to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\foorows{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addtotable[1]{%
  \g@addto@macro\foorows{\hline\@gobble}% Insert horizontal rule and gobble first &
  \@for\tmp:=#1\do{%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\foorows
      \expandafter{\expandafter&\tmp}%
  }%
  \g@addto@macro\foorows{\\}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| }
    \hline
    Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 & Header 4 \\ \hline % Header row
    \foorows
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\addtotable{R1C1,R1C2,R1C3,R1C4}
\addtotable{R2C1,R2C2,R2C3,R2C4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This cannot work, because, as you say, `\foorows` is called at the time where the table is typeset, and at this time, it is empty. You only fill it later. Somehow, you need to tell LaTeX *first* to look for the `\addtotable` macros and only then start with the actual typesetting. But what exactly is the application here? Why do you want it to be this way? I cannot quite imagine why you would want to do something like this ...

Comment: I'm using a predefined `pandoc` latex template that creates a table at the start of the document. The user using the template should be able to insert rows into that table

Comment: Would it be feasable that you place the table into another macro `\printtable` and the user executes this after having added all the rows?

Comment: You would have to write something to a file so that the next compilation can read and use it.

Comment: Found an answer!

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420224/show-table-defined-by-a-macro-before-assigning-its-elements