# Change separator in tex code / for loop

Tags: tables, tex-core, delimiters

I found this very useful macro to add rows to a table (while defining the rows externally from the table):
[Command to continually add to table with a command/macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341916/command-to-continually-add-to-table-with-a-command-macro/341925#341925)

In my case the macro has only some changes, it works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\PutLongtableRows{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\AddLongtableRow[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\PutLongtableRows{\@gobble}%
    \@for\tmp:=#1\do{%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\PutLongtableRows
        \expandafter{\expandafter&\tmp}%
    }%
    \g@addto@macro\PutLongtableRows{\\*\nobreakhline}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\AddLongtableRow{5.9,5.8,R2C3,R2,3C}
\AddLongtableRow{R2C1,RCC2C2,R2C3,R2,3C}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}}
    \caption{Blabla}
    \\*\nobreakhline\nobreakhline
    \PutLongTableRows
    \nobreakhline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Now I face the problem of the comma separation. I need to change the separator since numbers in our report have a comma. So the following will definitely lead to a wrong table:

```
\AddLongtableRow{5,9,5,8,R2C3,R2,3C}
```

If i could change the separator i. e. to semicolon ; it could work like this:

```
\AddLongtableRow{5,9;5,8;R2C3;R2;3C}
```

How to change the comma separator to another one? If I leave the & in the macro it will not work either even after removing the for loop...
Appreciate your help (if possible without additional packages).

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please provide a minimum working example that compiles.

Comment: Can't you simply put braces around the number? \AddLongtableRow{{5,5},9,}  should work fine.

Comment: Yes - that's indeed the most simple way to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I use `listofitems` to achieve a different parsing character, so that commas can now appear in the table data.

EDITED to make the row separator optionally specified as an argument to `\AddLongtableRow`.  Default is `,` but can be changed, as in row 3 of the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,listofitems}
\newcommand\PutLongtableRows{}
\newcommand\nobreakhline{\hline}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\AddLongtableRow[2][,]{%
    \g@addto@macro\PutLongtableRows{\@gobble}%
    \setsepchar{#1}% LISTOFITEMS SEP CHAR
    \readlist\z{#2}% READ THE LIST INTO \z
    \foreachitem\tmp\in\z{% LISTOFITEMS DO LOOP
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\PutLongtableRows
        \expandafter{\expandafter&\tmp}%
    }%
    \g@addto@macro\PutLongtableRows{\\*\nobreakhline}%
}
\makeatother

\AddLongtableRow{5.9,5.8,R2C3,R2,3C}
\AddLongtableRow{R2C1,RCC2C2,R2C3,R2,3C}
\AddLongtableRow[;]{5,9;5,8;R2C3;R2;3C}
\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}}
    \caption{Blabla}
    \\*\nobreakhline\nobreakhline
    \PutLongtableRows
    \nobreakhline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! There is another little question: As you see the first two lines and the last two lines are falling together. When using \hline instead of \nobreakhline it shows up two separated lines. How to manage this with \nobreakhline (see also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528814/longtable-behaviour-of-adapted-hline-nobreakhline)

Comment: @konsens I would note that achieving double-broken lines is not achieved by anything in the `\AddLongTableRow` macro, but rather by changing the `\nobreakhline`s to `\hline`s that have been manually added to the `longtable`.  So I am not exactly clear what you mean by "manage this"?

Comment: Yes, it's not about \AddLongTableRow anymore. \hline was modified to be \nobreakhline. However I want that two \nobreakhlines behave the same (apart from pagebreak behavieour) as two \hlines. But they don't. Two \nobreakhlines are falling togehter two \hlines are showing up as two separated \hlines (see question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528814/longtable-behaviour-of-adapted-hline-nobreakhline). Any idea?

Comment: @konsens That is the purpose (and the name **nobreak**hline): to act differently than `\hline`.  They only act *the same* if they occur as singles.  When occurring in multiples, each `\hline` makes a new line, whereas each `\nobreakhline` will *never* make a new line.  Your only alternative is to use something like `\myhline` inside your table, where you either `\let\myhline\hline` or else `\let\myhline\nobreakhline` in advance.

Comment: @konsens There is no doubt I have little experience with `\nobreakhline`.  Someone like David Carlisle (who probably wrote the macro code) would be a better resource than I on this follow-up question.  Good luck!

Comment: Ok, thx! It seems to be more complicated. Tried \let\myhline\nobreakhline but it does not really help. How to contact David Carlisle?

Comment: @konsens You can go to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends and write something `@DavidCarlisle`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simpler `expl3` implementation, which allows to change the delimiter at calling time (default is a comma).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,colortbl}
\usepackage{xparse}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107893/4427
\makeatletter
\def\nobreakhline{%
\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
 \penalty\@M
\futurelet\@let@token\LT@@nobreakhline}
\def\LT@@nobreakhline{%
\ifx\LT@next\hline
  \global\let\LT@next\@gobble
 \ifx\CT@drsc@\relax
   \gdef\CT@LT@sep{%
     \noalign{\penalty\@M\vskip\doublerulesep}}%
 \else
   \gdef\CT@LT@sep{%
     \multispan\LT@cols{%
       \CT@drsc@\leaders\hrule\@height\doublerulesep\hfill}\cr}%
 \fi
\else
 \global\let\LT@next\empty
 \gdef\CT@LT@sep{%
   \noalign{\penalty\@M\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}%
\fi
\ifnum0=`{\fi}%
\multispan\LT@cols
 {\CT@arc@\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill}\cr
\CT@LT@sep
\multispan\LT@cols
 {\CT@arc@\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill}\cr
\noalign{\penalty\@M}%
\LT@next}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_konsens_tablerow_tl
\seq_new:N \l__konsens_tablerow_seq

\NewDocumentCommand\AddLongtableRow{O{,}m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__konsens_tablerow_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_konsens_tablerow_tl
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l__konsens_tablerow_seq { & } 
    \exp_not:n { \\*\nobreakhline} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\PutLongTableRows}{}
 {
  \tl_use:N \g_konsens_tablerow_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddLongtableRow[;]{5,9;5,8;R2C3;R2;3C}
\AddLongtableRow{R2C1,RCC2C2,R2C3,R2,3C}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}}
    \caption{Blabla}
    \\*\nobreakhline\nobreakhline
    \PutLongTableRows
    \nobreakhline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Here is a small variation on [egreg's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527939/73317) (+1). The user-visible differences are:

- `\PutLongTableRows` allows you to choose the separator between rows. For instance, using `\PutLongTableRows[\\]` won't insert any rule between consecutive rows (the optional argument defaults to `\\*\nobreakhline`, since this seems to be your preference).
- `\PutLongTableRows` doesn't append the separator after the last row. This way, you can use whatever seems most appropriate in this place—the “finish” doesn't have to be identical as the separator between two adjacent rows.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xparse}

% From <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107893/4427>
\makeatletter
\def\nobreakhline{%
\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
 \penalty\@M
\futurelet\@let@token\LT@@nobreakhline}
\def\LT@@nobreakhline{%
\ifx\LT@next\hline
  \global\let\LT@next\@gobble
 \ifx\CT@drsc@\relax
   \gdef\CT@LT@sep{%
     \noalign{\penalty\@M\vskip\doublerulesep}}%
 \else
   \gdef\CT@LT@sep{%
     \multispan\LT@cols{%
       \CT@drsc@\leaders\hrule\@height\doublerulesep\hfill}\cr}%
 \fi
\else
 \global\let\LT@next\empty
 \gdef\CT@LT@sep{%
   \noalign{\penalty\@M\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}%
\fi
\ifnum0=`{\fi}%
\multispan\LT@cols
 {\CT@arc@\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill}\cr
\CT@LT@sep
\multispan\LT@cols
 {\CT@arc@\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill}\cr
\noalign{\penalty\@M}%
\LT@next}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_konsens_tablerows_seq
\seq_new:N \l__konsens_tablerow_seq

% Based on egreg's answer: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527939/73317>
\NewDocumentCommand \AddLongtableRow { O{,} m }
 {
   \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__konsens_tablerow_seq {#1} {#2}
   \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_konsens_tablerows_seq
     { \seq_use:Nn \l__konsens_tablerow_seq { & } }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \PutLongTableRows { O{\\*\nobreakhline} }
  {
    \seq_use:Nn \g_konsens_tablerows_seq {#1}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddLongtableRow[;]{5,9;5,8;R2C3;R2;3C}
\AddLongtableRow{R2C1,RCC2C2,R2C3,R2,3C}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}}
    \caption{Blabla}
    \\*\nobreakhline\nobreakhline
    \PutLongTableRows
    \\*\nobreakhline
    \nobreakhline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}}
    \caption{Blabla}
    \\*\nobreakhline\nobreakhline
    \PutLongTableRows[\\]
    \\*\nobreakhline
    \nobreakhline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]